# Why mongodb won't create a new database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Whenever I try to register a new user on my website or search for something stored in the database the connection can't get through to the database. I am using node.js and MongoDB. This is how I configured the connection to the server in `app.js`

```
mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Tuskdb", { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

When I check the mongo console for databases with the command `show dbs` I don't get my database listed. However, when I run my server using `nodemon app.js` I get no errors related to the database even though the connection doesn't go through. It just gives me a

> This page isn’t working
>
> localhost didn’t send any data.
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

in the browser, but nothing in the console. When I try to create a new database by changing my route to say :

```
mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/newdb", { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

It won't do it.
What do you think happened? I am not sure what kind of additional information I
need to provide, so let me know in the comments.

Comment: are you using express and mongoose in your stack ? In that case just run `npm update`

Comment: I am using both of them

Answer (score 1):

first you have to add error call back function an print it

```
mongoose.connect(`"mongodb://localhost:27017/Tuskdb"`, function(error) {
    if(error){
        console.log("error in creating connection",error);
    }else{
    console.log(`monogodb connected)
    }
  });
```

Comment: I get `error in creating connection Error: Invalid schema, expected 'mongodb' or 'mongodb+srv'`

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813584/invalid-schema-expected-mongodb

Comment: I rest my case, he had an issue of syntax. Mine is different

Comment: have you open mongod file ?

Comment: Yes, it is listening for any connections. It's baffling!